# How to get attributes of nested object with ngFor

Tags: html, json, angular

I am trying to show the value of "type" in `ngFor` table but I was getting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

> NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

**json**

```
[{
 "id": 123, 
 "name": "Paul", 
 "cars":
    {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013"
    }
 },
 {
 "id": 126, 
 "name": "Frank"
 },
 {
 "id": 125, 
 "name": "Joy", 
 "cars":
    {
     "type": "bwm", 
     "year": "2000"
    }
 },
 {
 "id": 133, 
 "name": "Bob"
}]
```

**html**

```
//....
<tr *ngFor="let info of information;">
   <td>{{info.name}}</td>
   <td *ngFor="let info2 of info.cars;"> //I want to loop through and get the type value of cars
   <td>{{info2.type}}</td>
   </td>
   <td><button type="button" (click)="showDetail()">View</button></td>
</tr>
//...
```

Some object has cars, how to I get the type value in the table? Another area I would need help is, how to show the "type" value (for object that has cars attribute) on a  input field when "View" button is clicked. Below is my .ts file where I need to grab the type value:

**comp.ts**

```
//....
information = [];
carsType= {};  to hold type value for objects that has it

showDetail(data: any) {
   this.formData.controls.name.setValue( data.name );
     // how do I get cars "type" value for each object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-81mclv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr *ngFor="let info of information;">
        <td>{{info.name}}</td>
        <td>{{info.cars?.type}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" (click)="carType = info.cars?.type">View</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="carType"/>
```

Comment: it works thank. But please can I pass the carType to a <select> field in a form instead of just <input> like in your answer? <select formControlName="serviceCar">
 <option [value]="servicecar.type" *ngFor="let servicecar of cList$">
    <td>{{ servicecar.type }}</td>
 </option>
</select>

Comment: ya, you can do that. Also if you have multiple cars,  modify json like this: "cars":
    {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013"
    }
 }  and have loop

Comment: You used [(ngModel)]="carType", but in my form I used formControlName="serviceCar". How do I bind it to the select field?

Comment: Check the modified demo

Comment: Added the demo with formControlName="serviceCar".

Comment: Sorry, I still need some clarifications. Instead of what you did, I am doing this in the button; (click)="info()" to get obj and not "info.cars?.type". Your demo works bcz u're handling single field. Since I am working with object, pls see my .ts, how do I set the "type" value with just like in the case of "...name.setValue"?

Comment: Great, Cheers :)

Comment: Adrita, with my half solution it works when my obj has the "cars" obj(i.e in the case of bmw and toyota) but I got undefined error when no cars obj. Can you tip me on how to fix the last line of this code: showDetail(data: any) {
    this.formData.controls.name.setValue( data.name );
      // works if type has value but I got error if no value
    this.formData.controls.serviceCar.setValue( data.cars.type );
 }

Comment: setValue(data ? data.name : "")

Comment: See, this code works: this.formData.controls.serviceCar.setValue( data.cars.type ); [That is, the "setValue(data.cars.type)" sets bmw or toyota when the car obj is present, but gave error when "setValue(data.cars.type)" is empty.] How do I set value when available and set empty string when no value? Here: "setValue(data.cars.type)"

Comment: data.cars  ? data.cars.type : ""

Comment: It works as needed now. Please accept my appreciations! Have a great day!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let info of information;">
  <td>{{info.name}}</td>
  <td>{{info?.cars?.type}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" (click)="showDetail()">View</button></td>
</tr>
```